# When will we see an amp (or amp-story) and algolia search integration, such as an amp-algolia-autocomplete?

Tags: search, autocomplete, amp-html, algolia, amp-story

Many, if not most websites, offer a search bar on the home page. Algolia offer a relatively easy to use search solution called autocomplete.

When will we see an amp or amp-story integration with Algolia's autocomplete?

example: **amp-algolia-autocomplete**

Comment: This is a great opportunity for a developer in the community to build a plugin.  For example, the [hexo-algolia][1] plugin is unofficial but has been very helpful for the community. If you don't see what you want, help out by giving it a shot!


  [1]: https://github.com/oncletom/hexo-algolia

Comment: what is the relationship between hexo and accelerated mobile pages?